# How can I set the background color of SceneView to transparent?

Tags: android, kotlin, sceneview

I am currently developing an Android app in Kotlin and I am using SceneView (https://github.com/SceneView/sceneview-android), since Sceneform was deprecated, to import a 3D Model to my scene. However, I am not being able to set SceneView's background color to transparent (or change it to other color besides black and white).

I have an activity that has two fragments, one of them fits to the whole size of the screen, the other is the SceneView fragment that occupies part of it. [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akyvh.jpg)

Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.NavigationActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentCamera"
        android:name="com.example.easier.view.CameraFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentSceneView"
        android:name="com.example.easier.view.SceneViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.20" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.SceneViewFragment">

    <io.github.sceneview.SceneView
        android:id="@+id/sceneView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In my fragment, I changed the background color to white with `mSceneView.backgroundColor = colorOf(255f, 255f, 255f, 1f)`, but when I put the alpha = 0f, the whole fragment stays black.

I have also tried adding `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to `@+id/sceneView`, but the whole fragment stays black.

Also, if I change `mSceneView.backgroundColor` to any other color, p.e., `mSceneView.backgroundColor = colorOf(132f, 63f, 18f, 1f)`, it remains white.

SceneView Fragment:

```
class SceneViewFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mSceneView: SceneView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[NavigationViewModel::class.java]
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scene_view, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mSceneView = view.findViewById(R.id.sceneView)

        val modelNode = ModelNode()
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            modelNode.loadModel(
                context = requireContext(),
                lifecycle = lifecycle,
                glbFileLocation = "low_poly_arrow/scene.gltf",
                autoAnimate = true,
                autoScale = true
            )
        }

        modelNode.scale = Scale(2.5f)
        modelNode.centerModel()
        mSceneView.addChild(modelNode)
        mSceneView.backgroundColor = colorOf(255f, 255f, 255f, 1f)
    }
}
```

There is still too little information about **sceneview-android**, I would appreciate some help!

Comment: change background-color of your activity then do whatever with your fragment

Comment: i have tried that, but it has no impact in the sceneview's background color

Comment: if you set background-color of your activity to white and add android:background="@android:color/transparent" to @+id/sceneView, still the whole fragment stays black?

Comment: yes, it remains all black. I've also tried mSceneView.backgroundColor = colorOf(255f, 255f, 255f, 0f) instead of android:background="@android:color/transparent" to @+id/sceneView

Comment: use null for color in style app <item name="android:windowBackground">null</item>

Comment: if I did it correctly, it had no impact as well